# How do I use mathematical symbols in verbatim mode?

Tags: verbatim

How can I get mathematical symbols in verbatim mode? If I use them, for example \equiv, it is just reproduced as is in the pdf.

Comment: It sounds like you don't really want verbatim (which means produce the output, erm, verbatim). What do you really want?

Comment: I want to include some code. For that I want to use the verbatim mode so that I dont have to do all the indentation, etc. And in that code, there are some symbols. What can I do?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `alltt`, `fancyvrb` or `listings` package for this purpose.

For `fancyvrb`, see manual "4.1.16 Catcode characters". Example:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},
  codes={\catcode‘$=3\catcode‘^=7}]
x=1/sqrt(z**2) ! $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2}}$
\end{Verbatim}
```

It is easier to use `listings` package, see manual "4.14 Escaping to LaTeX". Example:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
// calculate $a_{ij}$
$a_{ij} = a_{jj}/a_{ij}$;
\end{lstlisting}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you include the alltt package like this:

```
\usepackage{alltt} %verbatim boxes with latex commands
```

Then create math within an alltt environment using `\ensuremath{...}`

```
\begin{alltt}\small\center
\ensuremath{\neg}((P \ensuremath{\wedge} S) \ensuremath{\oplus} S)
\end{alltt}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might try the alltt package.