# Using math mode escapes with listings enabled fancyvrb

Tags: math-mode, listings, verbatim, fancyvrb

I am trying to escape math mode within `Verbatim`, using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16302/how-do-i-use-mathematical-symbols-in-verbatim-mode#16305). This works fine, until I use the listings package with `fancyvrb=true`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
% fancyvrb=true,%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},codes={\catcode`$=3\catcode`^=7}]
x=1/sqrt(z**2) ! $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2}}$
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

If I enable the `fancyvrb=true`, I get the following error: `Missing $ inserted.` And then nothing works.

---

**EDIT**: Taking the idea of adding `mathescape=true` from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63845/boldface-and-subscripts-in-verbatim-mode#63846), it seems to work in some cases, in others not:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
fancyvrb=true,%
mathescape=true,%
}

\begin{document}

Outside of verbatim: $\mathsf{lb}_\mathsf{pre}$:

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},codes={\catcode`$=3\catcode`^=7}]
x=1/sqrt(z**2) ! $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2}}$
Vertex = ($\mathsf{lb}_\mathsf{pre}$: Label, $\mathsf{lb}_\mathsf{post}$: Label)
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

The subscript still doesn't work inside the verbatim:

[image]

---

If there is no solution to this, how could I disable listings temporarily for one particular `Verbatim` block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change locally the setting with `formatcom`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
 fancyvrb=true,%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},
  codes={\catcode`$=3\catcode`^=7},
  formatcom={\lstset{fancyvrb=false}}]
x=1/sqrt(z**2) ! $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2}}$
\end{Verbatim}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},
  codes={\catcode`$=3\catcode`^=7\catcode`_=8},
  formatcom={\lstset{fancyvrb=false}}]
x=1/sqrt(z**2) ! $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2}}$
Vertex = ($\mathsf{lb}_\mathsf{pre}$: Label, $\mathsf{lb}_\mathsf{post}$: Label)
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

The `\lstset` is local, so it won't propagate to the following `listings` environments. For the subscripts you have to reset also the category code of `_`.

[image]