# \sim needs to display in Verbatim

Tags: fancyvrb

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass[executive,twoside, justified, symmetric, notoc, openany]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newcommand{\VerbBar}{|}
\newcommand{\VERB}{\Verb[commandchars=\\\{\}]}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
\newenvironment{Shaded}{}{}
%\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{literate={-}{-}1,fancyvrb=true,basicstyle=\sffamily,columns=flexible}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\KeywordTok}[1]{\color{cyan}{#1}}
\newcommand{\NormalTok}[1]{\color{cyan}#1}
\newcommand{\OperatorTok}[1]{\color{cyan}{#1}}
\newcommand{\StringTok}[1]{\color{cyan}{#1}}
\newcommand{\CommentTok}[1]{\textcolor{gray}{\textrm{#1}}}

$\sim$

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\KeywordTok{lm}\NormalTok{(co}\OperatorTok{$}\NormalTok{gdp }\OperatorTok{~}\StringTok{ }\NormalTok{co}\OperatorTok{$}\NormalTok{prior_gdp) }\CommentTok{# fits linear model}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}


\end{document}
```

Output produced as:

[image]

My requirement is to match the `\sim` output should match inside program code, i.e., need to use `\sim` in both in program code and in text

PS: Excuse me for my language skill...

I tried this, [Using math mode escapes with listings enabled fancyvrb](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102721/using-math-mode-escapes-with-listings-enabled-fancyvrb) but couldn't fix my need...

Comment: You probably means that you what the tilde char `~` to look like `\sim` (might want to update your title and text with that as it makes your problem easier to understand). There should be solutions to this on the site.

Comment: @daleif Most of the places, `$\sim$` only came, very few places, especially inside program code only `~` came, so it is helpful, if you suggest how to get `\sim` instead of `~` symbol

Comment: I don't know a solution but you mentioned your language skills, so I mention that the term tilde might be a good idea to use in your question and title as it makes it easier to understand. I would change the title to something similar to `Tilde (~) should show like $\sim$ in verbatim text`

Comment: @daleif Kindly feel free to edit if you want to make any modification...

Comment: IMHO it looks *much* better as is, but is there are reason you can't write something like `\OperatorTok{\ensuremath{\sim}}` (or possibly `\OperatorTok{\ensuremath{\sim\ }}` to get a trailing space)?

Comment: Or are you trying to make the first more like the second? Then don't use `\sim`, use `\textasciitilde`.or `\texttt{\textasciitilde}` for the typewriter version.

Comment: @frabjous Your suggestion works perfectly...

Comment: In all your `\…Tok` commands you should have `\textcolor`, not `\color`

Comment: @egreg I'll correct it and thanks for your advise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\newcommand\Sim{\ensuremath{\sim}}

\Sim

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\KeywordTok{lm}\NormalTok{(co}\OperatorTok{$}\NormalTok{gdp }\OperatorTok{\Sim}\StringTok{ 
}\NormalTok{co}\OperatorTok{$}\NormalTok{prior_gdp) }\CommentTok{# fits linear model}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}
```

[image]